# How to connect LCD display to a potentiometer?

Tags: glcd

I am new in electronic therefore please bear with me about my explaination.

I have a LCD display made by TGK model TM12864L, please see manual and diagram attached.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/71681740/TM12864L-1-TGK-manual.pdf

It requires a potentiometer connect to pin 3 and pin 18 of the LCD.

- pin 3 is Vo ( operating voltage )
- pin 18 is Vout ( negative voltage output )

The potentiometer diagram shows: Vo connects to the middle wiper, Vdd and Vout connect to the other 2 legs.

The manual also indicates: Vlcd - Vo = - 4.7 Volt

I am really confused which leg of the potentiometer should connect to pin 3 and pin 18 and where the other leg should connect to ?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The bottom left corner of section 4 of the datasheet explains how to connect the pot to VOUT, VDD, and V0.

Comment: Is that mean the wiper of the potentiometer connect to pin 3, the side leg Vout connect to pin 18 and other leg connect to the power source ? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: That's what the datasheet says.